# Uploading image with AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-upload, uiimageview, afnetworking-2

I'm banging my head against the wall with this one. I want to select `UIImage` from library and upload it to server, like on could do with `<form action="http://blabla.request.cfm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`. Instead of success I got this error:

> error = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x145e5d90 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

I tried this way:

```
-(void)uploadPhoto{
NSString *path = @"http://blabla.request.cfm";
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imageView.image, 0.9);
int priv = self.isPrivate ? 1 : 0;
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username": self.username, @"password" : self.password, @"private" : @(priv), @"photo" : imageData};
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager POST:path parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    if(self.imageView.image){
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"avatar" fileName:@"avatar.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    }
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"[UploadVC] success = %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"[UploadVC] error = %@", error);
}];

[self blockView:self.view block:YES];
}
```

but it's not working... server says that there is no file. Not sure if encrypting is wrong, mime type or what?

Tried also this:

```
    [manager POST:path parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"[UploadVC] success = %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"[UploadVC] error = %@", error);
}];
```

and this:

```
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager POST:path parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFormData:imageData name:@"photo"];
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"[UploadVC] success = %@", responseObject);
    [self blockView:self.view block:NO];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"[UploadVC] error response.object = %@", operation.responseObject);
    [self blockView:self.view block:NO];
}];
```

nothing is working. Hope someone can help, 'cause I'm stuck with it and circling from question to question here on SO
tia

**EDIT**: new attempt
1) first was multi-part form
2) creating upload task
none of them worked for me, so I'm still trying to cope with that, but cannot see any solution

Comment: What is the log of [operation responseString] on failure block ?

Comment: you mean from the first example? it is html file from server with table containing info on error (from coldfusion)

Comment: actually it is really messy, but from it I can find that section Diagnostic says: The form field photo did not contain a file

Comment: I don't know whats wrong in this parameter

    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"public.image" fileName:@"photo.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];

Answer (score 94, accepted):

I'm not sure which part (I think that some details were missing) was responsible, but I did it  finally :) here you go:

```
-(void)uploadPhoto{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://server.url"]];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.avatarView.image, 0.5);
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username": self.username, @"password" : self.password};
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [manager POST:@"rest.of.url" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        //do not put image inside parameters dictionary as I did, but append it!
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:paramNameForImage fileName:@"photo.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);
    }];
    [op start];
}
```

Works like a charm :)

Comment: rest of server url, notice that base url is in `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` init method

Comment: Whats the need for "[op start];" ? I did this in the same way as above  but link returns success, but file not uploaded to the server.

Comment: [op start]; -->to start uploading.

Comment: @raistlin Hey, this code works for me, but same code with session manager doesn't work. Maybe you have an idea why this happens?

Comment: what is name:paramNameForImage can u please help me

Comment: I don't know whats wrong in this parameter

    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"public.image" fileName:@"photo.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];

Comment: Is there a way to do it that isn't loading a file into memory?

Answer (score 2):

You can upload an image with `AFNetworking` using `Swift` like this...

```
    let compression = 0.5

    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation("image", CGFloat(compression))

if imageData != nil{
   var manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
        manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = NSSet(array: ["text/html", "application/json"]) as Set<NSObject>

        var dictParams = [
        "familyId":"10000",
        "contentBody" : "Some body content for the test application",
        "name" : "the name/title",
        "typeOfContent":"photo"
    ]

        let url = "http://...."
        manager.POST(url, parameters: dictParams, constructingBodyWithBlock: { (formData: AFMultipartFormData!) -> Void in
            //code
            formData.appendPartWithFileData(imageData, name: "file", fileName: "filename", mimeType: "image/png")
            }, success: { (operation:AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject:AnyObject!) -> Void in
                println(responseObject)
            }, failure: { (operation:AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
                println(error)
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"decline_clicked.png"];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1);


NSString *queryStringss = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://your server/uploadfile/"];
queryStringss = [queryStringss stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];


[manager POST:queryStringss parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
 {


     [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"fileName" fileName:@"decline_clicked.png" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];



 }
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {



    NSDictionary *dict = [responseObject objectForKey:@"Result"];

    NSLog(@"Success: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, responseObject);


 }
      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {

     NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);
 }];
```