# How to sent image to server with base64Encoding using HTTP POST in iOS

Tags: ios, uiimage, base64

I'm try to upload a image to server which is in base64Encoded data form. There is two parameter in url 'data' and 'type' of image. Can anyone suggest how can i do this?

Comment: Check this answer, this might help for you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836432/uploading-image-with-afnetworking-2-0

Comment: Making HTTP Post Connnection this will help. Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537297/ios-how-to-perform-an-http-post-request