# How to upload images in the background in ios using Afnetworking

Tags: ios, image-uploading, afnetworking-2

I want to upload images from an iOS app to a php server.  I am currently using POST Multi-Part Request in AFNetworkingOperationManager.

What I want to do is that  when a user taps to upload image, Its starts uploading in the background and then a user can migrate away to a different controller. And when the upload the finished, The image is added to the list of images in a different controller where they are displayed in a table view just like twitter.

Can I accomplish this using AFNetworking?

Comment: Check [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19841957/815540). Please do some research before posting as these things are very trivial.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading image with AFNetworking 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836432/uploading-image-with-afnetworking-2-0)

Answer (score 1):

Yes ,you can get it, First ,I aways get a mutableArray instead of some paths of picture, then you can upload them in background.