# How to Upload Images Using AFNetworking directly from iPad app

Tags: ios, ipad, afnetworking

I am totally new to iOS.I want to upload images to my server using **AFNetworking**.
I tried it but it still not done. Please Help me, thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uploading image with AFNetworking 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836432/uploading-image-with-afnetworking-2-0)

Comment: You should google before asking questions, there are many answers to your questions in other posts.

Comment: i tried it but using that answer i am not able get answer using that, its generates error

Comment: You should tell the error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try with this its work for me

```
-(void) uplodeImages{

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager   alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url where to upload images"]];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage    imageNamed:@"cat1.png"]);
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username": @"", @"password" : @""};
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [manager POST:@"cat1.png" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        //do not put image inside parameters dictionary as I did, but append it!
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"userfile" fileName:@"cat1.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);
    }];
    [op start];
}
```

Comment: Ya, this is helpful for me. Thnaks Sachin Partil

Comment: none of the success or failure blocks are called, do you know why?

Comment: @Septronic nice ans but i have a ques if you can help me out ..can i send **image(with key)**, **audio file(with key)** and string values (dict parameters) together using this code ..? **please help if you little time**