# How to upload hundreds of pictures by AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, afnetworking, image-uploading

I would like to upload pictures, probably ranging from a few hundred to 1000, originally using AFNetwoking methods, but there is a drawback, it reads all image data one time, then memory is up，for example:

```
NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init]；
[operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];

for (NSURL *fileURL in filesToUpload) {
      NSURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"  
       URLString:@"http://example.com/upload" parameters:nil 
       constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
            [formData appendPartWithFileURL:fileURL name:@"images[]" error:nil];
       }];

       AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

      [operationQueue addOperation:operation];
}
```

this will read all pictures's data before upload, how can i create a queue reduced memory consumption

Comment: Create the new operations in batches or even one by one.

Comment: You can use multipart to upload the images, check this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410689/iphone-upload-multipart-file-using-afnetworking).

Comment: Similar question asked here [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28716100/how-to-upload-images-using-afnetworking-directly-from-ipad-app