# iOS: Unable to upload image through restful api

Tags: php, ios, image-uploading, afnetworking-2

I am having the hardest time trying to upload an image from ios to the web server through a PHP script. I have already test the php script with an html form and it worked perfectly, but I am having a lot of trouble when sending from the phone.

I am currently using AFNetworking 2.0 and set it up like the following:

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myexamplesite.com"]];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [manager POST:@"mobile_app/upload.php" parameters:nil
                     constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        //do not put image inside parameters dictionary as I did, but append it!
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:_worldmoonproject.imageData name:@"file" fileName:@"photo.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);
    }];
    [op start];
```

And in the NSLog it is only spitting out the following:

> 2015-08-18 17:45:37.378 WMP[3265:280005] Success:  ***** (null)

Here is my server code:

```
if(!empty($_POST))
{
    //The directory to save the photos
    define('MB', 1048576);
    $errors = array();
    $target_dir = "app_data/images/";
    $file_name = md5(date('Y-m-d H:i:s:u'));
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $upload_valid = false;
    $file_type = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    //Verify the file is an image
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);

    if ($check !== false) 
    {
        $upload_valid = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $upload_valid = false;
        $errors[] = "FILE_NOT_IMAGE";
    }

    //Check if the file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file))
    {
        $upload_valid = false;
        $errors[] = "FILE_ALREADY_UPLOADED";
    }

    //Verify the file is not too large
    if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 500*MB)
    {
        //the file is too large, display an error
        $upload_valid = false;
        $errors[] = "FILE_TOO_LARGE";
    }

    //Only allow image file types
    if ($file_type != "jpg" && $file_type != "png" && $file_type != "jpeg")
    {
        $upload_valid = false;
        $errors[] = "INVALID_FILE_TYPE";
    }

    //Verify the file is valid and upload it
    if ($upload_valid)
    {
        //the file is valid
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir . $newfilename))
        {
            $msg = array('FILE_UPLOAD_SUCCESS' => "File uploaded successfully");
            echo json_encode($msg);
        }
        else
        {
            $msg = array("FILE_UPLOAD_FAIL" => "Unable to upload file");
            echo json_encode($msg);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //echo the error array in json
        echo json_encode($errors);
    }
}
```

Comment: check answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836432/uploading-image-with-afnetworking-2-0) might be related.