# Upload Image with AfNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, afnetworking-3

I am trying to Upload imageData (Image That is selected from gellery Or camera and set on UIImageview) with AFNetworking.Here is my code :

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [[manager POST:setUrl parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
            [formData appendPartWithFileData:image name:namePara fileName:@"abc.png"mimeType:@"image/png"];
        } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }]resume];
```

I have try too much but i realize that the **uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request** block not compile anymore. and my **responseObject** is not log anymore. 

How can i do this?

Comment: Check out this posts accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836432/uploading-image-with-afnetworking-2-0

Answer (score 0):

**For AFNetworking 2.5 version:**

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

[manager POST:@"Your_API" parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
          [formData appendPartWithFileData:img_data name:@"param_name" fileName:@"abc.png"mimeType:@"image/png"];
        }
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);


    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Comment: AFHTTPRequestOperationManager is undeclare. how to get it?

Comment: @ChandraChothani Which version of `AFNetworking` you are using?

Comment: @ChandraChothani what is response or error?

Comment: No.manually Using. and No error or response i can show.bcz it's not enter in constructingBodyWithBlock block.

Comment: @iosDeveloper Check your internet speed, image size or your php side.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like,

```
 AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];


 [[manager POST:urlStrToUploadMedia parameters:parameter constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {

                    [formData appendPartWithFileData:dataToAppend name:mediaName fileName:mediaName mimeType:mimeType];

                } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nonnull responseObject) {

                    NSLog(@"response object : %@",responseObject);

                } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

                    NSLog(@"failure : %@",error.localizedDescription);


                }]resume];
```

Here `dataToAppend` is `Image converted to NSData`, `mediaName` is name of image(whatever you want to give), `mimeType` is mimeType like `image/jpeg` or `image/png` depeds on your image's type.

Comment: see my updated question. as you say i have set.but still not call that block

Comment: try with `AFHTTPSessionManager` manager. And check what you get success or failure?

Comment: i have try first AFHTTPSessionManager. but it want work. i dont know what happen

Comment: What error you got? I mean what happen ?

Comment: nothing to be happen. just call the block and after 20min  or more it will enter in sucess block.

Comment: That means your success block is getting execute. So, it is proper approach. Now problem may be slow internet connection or big image size. So compress image before send to make it faster. `NSData *dataToAppend = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, 0.5);' You can reduce quality to `0.1`. It's value should be between 0 to 1.

Comment: i am doing same like your post but it's not working. it will give me the error : error In Image Uploading.